# Javascript improving ajax call for populating select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to get some data and populate a select dropdown.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl here',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result.main, function(result, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.id).attr('value', value.id));
        });
    }
});
```

What I need to do after populating the select is to get the value of the 1st line populated in the select.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can set the `val()` of the select to the first item in the array. Try this:

```
success: function(result) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(result.main, function(result, value) {
        html += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.id + '</option>'
    });
    $('#myselect').append(html).val(result.main[0].id);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b6au8eqy/)

Alternatively if you want to force the selection to the first `option` within the select you can set the `selectedIndex` property to `0`:

```
$('#myselect').append(html).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Also note that I amended the loop to generate a single HTML string which is only appended to the DOM once, which is quicker than amending the DOM on each iteration.

*Update*

> I want to get the value of the first one and store it in a variable so I can use it later

In that case you can use `result.main[0].id`:

```
var first = result.main[0].id
```

Comment: I need to get the first line of the imported list after importing the list

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select the first option, not the first newly appended option? I updated the answer just in case

Comment: No, what I mean is that I want to get the value of the first one and store it in a variable so I can use it later

Comment: `var first = result.main[0].id`